# Could anyone tell the skill name is what?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I want to realise and implement a function. But I do not know what the skill name is what.
I reference the Gallery APP in android I found that Gallery have a function is when user browse the picture, the picture will display and dismiss automatically when it reach screen edge.
[image]

Just like the picture I draw, picture will show when it reach the screen edge.

Comment: I think the name you are looking for is "Image Carousel".

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Horizontal ScrollView`.
I also reecomend this library to you: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view
 Have a look here too: https://www.airpair.com/android/horizontal-image-galleries-android-studio
There is a library on `github` may be also helpful: `AndroidImageSlider`